# GET параметр не вставляется в метод find для mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Express принимает get параметр id, выводит его как в консоль, так и отправляет через send, но не вставляет в метод find `findOne({myId: id})` mongodb. Если вставить вместо переменной обычное число, все работает правильно. Если создать переменную `let id = 1` и вставить в find - тоже работает. С асинхронностью проблемы, наверно, нет, ведь параметр отправляется через send. Видимо проблема именно в методе find. Может быть проблема с самим пакетом mongodb или express?

```js
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
 const collection = req.app.locals.db.collection("users");
 let id = req.query.id;
 if(id) {
  collection.findOne({myId: id}, function(err, user){           
         if(err) return console.log(err);
         res.send(user);
     });
 }else {
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, users){
         if(err) return console.log(err);
         res.send(users)
     });
 }
 
});
```

Comment: Может, перевести id в число? Попробуйте `let id = +req.query.id`